# Working with IF/ELSE and inserting into temp tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, temp-tables

I'm trying to write a SQL query that accepts two inputs (a content ID and a content type), populates a temp table from different source tables depending on what the user sets as content type, and then finally runs a query against the temp table. I think I'm getting stuck on incorporating my temp table into my IF/ELSE statements.

So my question is, why does this return some non-zero number of results:

```
DECLARE @contentID int, @contenttype varchar
SET @contentid = 28861
SET @contenttype = 'resource'

DECLARE @tags_current TABLE (contentID int, taxonomyID int, isPrimary int)

INSERT INTO @tags_current (contentID, taxonomyID, isPrimary)
SELECT resourceID as contentID, taxonomyID, isPrimary
FROM resource2taxonomy r2t
WHERE r2t.resourceID = @contentID

SELECT * FROM @tags_current
```

Whereas this returns zero results:

```
DECLARE @contentID int, @contenttype varchar
SET @contentid = 28861
SET @contenttype = 'resource'

DECLARE @tags_current TABLE (contentID int, taxonomyID int, isPrimary int)

IF (@contenttype = 'resource')
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @tags_current (contentID, taxonomyID, isPrimary)
    SELECT resourceID as contentID, taxonomyID, isPrimary
    FROM resource2taxonomy r2t
    WHERE r2t.resourceID = @contentID
END

SELECT * FROM @tags_current
```

Also, I've tried this, and it also returns zero results:

```
DECLARE @contentID int, @contenttype varchar, @command varchar
SET @contentid = 28861
SET @contenttype = 'resource'

DECLARE @tags_current TABLE (contentID int, taxonomyID int, isPrimary int)

IF (@contenttype = 'resource')
BEGIN
    SET @command = 'INTO @tags_current (contentID, taxonomyID, isPrimary) SELECT resourceID as contentID, taxonomyID, isPrimary FROM resource2taxonomy r2t WHERE r2t.resourceID = @contentID'
END

EXECUTE(@command)
SELECT * FROM @tags_current
```

I've read up on [this](http://odetocode.com/articles/365.aspx), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712731/using-temp-tables-in-if-else-statements), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155996/sql-insert-into-temp-table-in-both-if-and-else-blocks), but for some reason it's just not clicking for me. I'm using MS SQL Server 2014, in case that helps. Here's the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bb748/3). Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually very simple, you aren't giving a length to `@contenttype`, as such, by default it's taking a length of 1 char.

This will be clear if you do this:

```
DECLARE @contentID int, @contenttype varchar
SET @contentid = 28861
SET @contenttype = 'resource'
SELECT @contenttype
```

The result is `r`, so, `IF (@contenttype = 'resource')` is not true

Comment: Thank you - this is the answer. It's too soon for me to accept it as the answer (cannot accept an answer within 10 minutes), but I will come back and do that.